# Python Selenium Chromedriver horizontal scroll not working

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am doing web scraping using Selenium Chromedriver in Python. Now for a grid (horizontally scroll-able) when I am trying to get the data ,I am getting only till the visible section of the grid in browser.

For ex. here I am only able to get data till `Part Category` , like this
`['', '', '', '', '', 'Item Number', 'Item Description', 'Lifecycle Phase', 'Old Lifecycle Phase', 'Docs Rqd', 'PGDS Audit', 'Part Category', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']` though there are few more columns does exists.

[image]

I have tried `actions.move_to_element` , `driver.execute_script` but not working .
Here is my sample code

```
for i in range(len(titles)):
    current_tab = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='tabsDiv']/ul/li/a")[i:i+1]
    current_tab_name=current_tab[0].text
    current_tab[0].click()
    time.sleep(5)
    if(current_tab_name=='Affected Items'):
        current_tab_info=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='GMHeadMid']/table[@class='GMSection']/tbody/tr[@class='GMHeaderRow']/td") ## this is the scroll-able grid  
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 100)")
        #current_tab_info[0].location_once_scrolled_into_view
        #actions = ActionChains(driver)
        #actions.move_to_element(current_tab_info[0]).perform()
        current_tab_header_list=[x.text for x in current_tab_info]
        print(current_tab_header_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make the driver scroll to the element instead of scrolling horizontally?

```
scrollToElement = "arguments[0].scrollIntoView()"

driver.execute_script(scrollToElement, current_tab_info)
```

I am no python expect, so could be something wrong in my syntax.

Comment: Yes tried that but no luck. Still getting the visible columns only

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got an workaround

```
# First of all get all the header column span IDs
current_tab_info = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='GMHeadMid']/table[@class='GMSection']/tbody/tr[@class='GMHeaderRow']/td/div/span")
current_tab_header_list = [x.get_attribute('id') for x in current_tab_info]

# Then get element text against each ID
current_tab_header_label_list =[]
        for i in current_tab_header_list:
            # will scroll until that element is not appeared on page
            current_header_info = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
                "//div[@class='GMHeadMid']/table[@class='GMSection']/tbody/tr[@class='GMHeaderRow']/td/div/span[@id='"+str(i)+"']")
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", current_header_info[0])
            current_tab_header_label_list.append(current_header_info[0].text)
```